# AttributeError: 'Move' object has no attribute 'button'; mouse listener with pynput

Tags: python, mouselistener, pynput

I wanted something that monitors a mouse event, to be more specific a left click. So I was already using the libary pynput so I looked up their documentation.
So I just copy pasted their code for "Synchronous event listening for the mouse listener".
This is the used code:

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False


with mouse.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.button == mouse.Button.left:
            break
        else:
            print('Received event {}'.format(event))
```

But as soon as I move my mouse I get the following error:
"if event.button == mouse.Button.left:
AttributeError: 'Move' object has no attribute 'button'"
If I don't move my mouse and only press left click it works as intended. But I want to first move my mouse and then press left click to kind of confirm this position where the mouse points at.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your buttons are different Button vs button

Comment: You need to check that the event is actually a mouse click event first, as that's the only kind of event that would meaningfully specify a particular mouse button.

Comment: How do I check that I got a mouse click event first? And where do I put it in? before the for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

Main problem was that `event` may not have attribute `.button` as the error indicates.

`mouse.Events()` can have 3 main types: `pynput.mouse.Events.Click`, `pynput.mouse.Events.Move` and `pynput.mouse.Events.Scroll` (as far as I know)

And among those three, last two of those do not have attribute `.button` surely.

So if we want to handle this problem, I guess we need to use exception handling. 
Check the codes below.

```
from pynput import mouse

with mouse.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        try:
            if event.button == mouse.Button.right:
                print('Right button clicked!')
                break
        except: pass
        finally:
            print('Received event {}'.format(event))
```

I think this works as we expect.